# Is there an algorithm to decide that the nonogram puzzle is unique

Tags: algorithm, nonogram

A good nonogram puzzle has a unique solution. However, some nonograms do not. For example, this puzzle:

```
      211 
    1311231
  1     
  3     
2 1   
1 1   
1 2   
  3   
  1
```

Has at least two solutions, shown below:

```
      211 
    1311231
  1 *------
  3 --***--
2 1 -**--*-
1 1 -*---*-
1 2 -*--**-
  3 --***--
  1 ------*      

      211 
    1311231
  1 *------
  3 -***---
2 1 -**-*--
1 1 -*---*-
1 2 --*-**-
  3 ---***-
  1 ------*
```

Is there an algorithm to decide that the puzzle has a unique solution that is more efficient than trying to solve it?

Comment: You want an algorithm that you can do with pen and paper or with a computer?

Comment: The former is better. However, computer algorithm is allowed unless it is just a bruteforce.

Comment: With dynamic programming you could presumably spit out all the solutions pretty quickly. But you don't want that?

Comment: @DrXorile I think the OP is looking for algorithms or formulae that don't actually solve it. Just like for example [this formula for checking for solvability of slide puzzles](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html)

Comment: Probably not, since determining whether a Nonogram has a solution is NP complete, as is determining whether a  Nonogram had an additional solution given a puzzle and a solution (see [here](http://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/assets/2012-01JanvanRijn.pdf), page 29).

Answer (score 1):

if the rows and columns are symmetric and you cannot find any black square from a row and from a column only, it is not unique and there is at least one more solution.

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit your statement to include proof that this is the case, and that this covers all the cases (if it does) and how you got to it.

Comment: I am on it, I will edit it after I got a solid proof.

Comment: How about nonsymmetric nonogram.

Comment: What does "find any black square from a row and from a column only" mean?  It is trivial to generate a symmetric puzzle with a unique solution (ex. every square is black).